# QGIS 3.22.11: Cannot save vector layer after modifications (OGR error, non-finite values)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, qgis-3, ogr

I have a (self-created) shapefile and add e.g. another polygon to the file (or delete a vertex or any other modification) then try to save the file and finish editing, and this message comes:

*Could not commit changes to layer "features"

Errors: ERROR: one feature not added.

Provider errors: OGR error creating feature -28: Coordinates with non-finite values are not allowed*

I tried to merge the features which works. And saw that the Id is negative. But I don't know why.
Any ideas how I can fix this? It happens with/in multiple layers in different projects.

[image: Screenshot as example]

Comment: Can you provide more details or share the file (even better). Otherwise, it's difficult to help.

Comment: Sure I can provide more detail, but unsure what exactly.
It seems that this "negative ID" is the problem, and it happens in mutiple files in multiple projects.
How can I share the file?